# Advice on what path to choose for a website

Tags: content-management-system

A friend has asked me to make a website for him, for a games arcade he runs. It's an extremely simple website so no big deal.

The thing is I'm not quite sure how to approach it, I haven't worked on sites in a while. It would probably be easiest for me to create the site entirely myself, a few pages, css and probably a bit of javascript. But then I thought what if he wants to change things himself in the future, so I should maybe use a cms like wordpress or drupal. The last cms I used was nopcommerce about 2 years ago so I'm not really up to speed with them and themes etc.

Back in uni we were making websites with xml, which sounds ideal as I could create pages that would remain unchanged then use xml for arcade machines and news updates which he could edit himself. But that was a few years ago, is that how things are done nowadays?

Apologies for sounding so stupid but I'd like to get into web design again and I just want the opinion of someone with a bit of experience as to how they would go forward with this so I can do things properly.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the first thing you need to ask him is "what do you want to do with the site?" since that's going to drive every other decision you make.  No point in throwing up a big complex CMS if all he wants is a blog.

Comment: If you just want to make your friend a website, try a blog with WordPress (easier) or Drupal (harder but does more). If you want to learn web development, do the pages in HTML, CSS, javascript (or jQuery) but please, not XML.

Comment: I think mainly it's for finding his place, contacting his place, having information on events and new machines and also have some sort of facebook integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found WordPress ok for smaller sites.

Things evolve quickly around the web and you would probably benefit from the large collection of available templates.

Comment: I'm more interested in the plugins that are available with cms's, like facebook, flikr things like that he would maybe want to be linked into his site. I would also like to do something slightly original rather than using someone elses template, but the whole template systems feel restrictive.

Comment: Actually, WP templating is very flexible. Download a few themes and stydy, get a good book (rockstar is alright) and you're on track. Don't rely too heavily on (too many) plugins. The ever-lasting updating is tiresome and they bog down your response-time. Estimate two days to get to know WP. You'll be fine.

Comment: wordpress does seem to be the cms of choice for small websites, thanks for the advice I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Use Wordpress. It's really easy to setup and you can find a lot of free plugins and themes to create a web site with professional aesthetic and basic functionality. Having your information in a database and the modularity of the product makes easy to scale to a bigger site later if it is needed.

Comment: i might go with wordpress, pick a compatible theme and spend a while changing it to suit.